# Finding n using central limit theorem

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem

> Problem 3: Central Limit
>
> Consider tossing a fair coin $100n$ times, where n is geometrically distributed with mean 6. Due to a counting error, it is reported that the fraction of heads is in $[0.5,0.51]$. What is the most likely value for $n$?

We've been using the de Moivre Laplace approximation using a standardized sum.

$$
P\left(.50\times100n\leq \frac{S_n -\frac{1}{p}}{\frac{\sqrt{1-p}}{p}}\leq .51\times100n\right) = S_n \Phi(b) - \Phi(a)
$$

and we start with $\frac{S_n}{n}$ and manipulate the bounds so we have $S_n^*$.

Which $\approx \Phi(285.34n) - \Phi(279.86n)$

I can't imagine this is correct. How does the Bernoulli trial enter the calculation?

Comment: Since $n \geq 1$, $\Phi(285.34n)$ and $\Phi(279.86n)$ are _so nearly the same number_ that any inference based on their difference is highly suspect.

Comment: The connection between a "counting error" and reporting an interval for the fraction is so obscure that it's difficult to determine what this question is asking, much less identify a meaningful way to answer it. Regardless, the point of @Dilip's comment is that the computation reported in the question is erroneous.

Comment: What a terrible question.  I assume this is supposed to be a confidence interval of come sort.  But then there should be only one value for $n$ that would give that width.  And then I don't see how to include the geometric distribution of $n$.  Does anyone have a good interpretation of this?